# Grails configuration read error

Tags: grails, config

I have a Service in my Grails application.
Trying to read configuration as shown below:

```
MyService {
     def grailsApplication
     def myMethode(params){
         def var = grailsApplication.config.com.application.document.extension
         .....
     }
```

gives the following exception:

```
no such property : com for class:MyService
```

Config.groovy:

```
    //....
    com.application.document.extension= [ 'Image' : [[mimeType:'image/png',extensions:     ['png']],
    [mimeType:'image/jpeg',extensions:['jpg','jpeg']]],
        'Document' : [[mimeType:'application/pdf',extensions:['pdf']],
       [mimeType:'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',extensions:['ppt','pps']],
       [mimeType:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-      officedocument.presentationml.presentation',extensions:['pptx']],
       [mimeType:'application/vnd.ms-excel',extensions:['xls']],
       [mimeType:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',extensions:['xlsx']],
       [mimeType:'application/msword',extensions:['doc']],
       [mimeType:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',extensions:['docx']],
       [mimeType:'image/png',extensions:['png']],
       [mimeType:'application/postscript',extensions:['ai','eps','psd']],
       [mimeType:'application/zip',extensions:['zip']],
       [mimeType:'text/plain',extensions:['txt']]]
]
```

Comment: Post your Config.groovy as well.

Comment: what version of grails?

Comment: com.application.document.extension= [ 'Image' : [[mimeType:'image/png',extensions:['png']],
 [mimeType:'image/jpeg',extensions:['jpg','jpeg']]],
'Document' : [[mimeType:'application/pdf',extensions:['pdf']],
    [mimeType:'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',extensions:['ppt','pps']]]
]

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you have no such property **com.application.document.extension** in Config.groovy. Post how you define it in question.

Comment: hi Mr. Cat ,
i have this in my config.groovy
com.application.document.extension= [ 'Image' : [[mimeType:'image/png',extensions:['png']],
 [mimeType:'image/jpeg',extensions:['jpg','jpeg']]],
'Document' : [[mimeType:'application/pdf',extensions:['pdf']],
    [mimeType:'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',extensions:['ppt','pps']],.....]